# SharePoint 2013 - Filtered View for a list based on value in a related list via a lookup column value

Tags: sharepoint

I have two SharePoint lists (only minimal columns described below for brevity).

The first has two columns, a text column called Name, and a person/group column called head of service.

The second has two columns, a lookup column called Service (which looks up from List1), and a text column called Value.

I would like to be able to create a view for the second list so it shows only the rows created by the current user AND any rows that the current user is Head of Service for - i.e. by looking at the relationship between the two tables and comparing the current user to the HeadOfService column in the first table.

I'm running in the Office365 SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: what is the problem, you can create view by using filter condition?

Comment: The problem is how do you set a filter like this up - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way for SharePoint to read who is viewing a list and show different views based on that alone, the best you're going to get are pre-made views per user based on Created By and Head of Service.